# MySQL, получаю ошибку 80001

Tags: sql-server

Я тут пытаюсь создать таблицу в БД. Использую VS 2017.  Мне выдает ошибку что я не могу просто так написать CREATE TABLE Case

> Ошибка SQL80001: Неверный синтаксис около "Case".  Ожидается '.', ID или QUOTED_ID.dbo.Table  1

Мне нужно просто назвать таблицу именем Case, но VS не дает мне это сделать даже через свойства.

```
CREATE TABLE Case
(
    [CaseID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    [Category] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Price] DECIMAL(16, 2) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: А ещё `Case` это ключевое слово в SQL, так что нужны кавычки, видимо.

Comment: MySQL или MSSQL? В вопросе указан MySQL, при этом используется синтаксис MSSQL.

Comment: Ох я не знал. Спасибо, а поставил я так CREATE TABLE "Case"